# Embedded jetty with vaadin 7

Tags: java, clojure, vaadin

I'm trying to set up a clojure environment for vaadin 7. With vaadin 6 I could use `AbstractApplicationServlet` which provides the application class. I can then do in clojure repl `(use 'foo.bar.core :reload) (restart)` to reload the servlet immediately (without waiting for recompiling / repackaging / waiting for jvm to start).

I am now trying to do the same with Vaadin 7. The migration guide in [Migrating from Vaadin 6 to 7](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7) mentions that `AbstractApplicationServlet` has been replaced by `VaadinServlet`. `VaadinServlet` however does not provide similar hooks to provide the default `UI` class. How can I use an embedded jetty with vaadin 7?

Comment: I don't know how Clojure works, but this is how I added Vaadin 7 into Grails: https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/blob/master/grails-vaadin7-plugin/src/groovy/com/vaadin/grails/GrailsVaadinServlet.groovy maybe you could use the same approach?

Comment: I wrote a blog post about using Vaadin 7 with Clojure: http://codebrickie.com/blog/2013/02/12/using-vaadin-7-with-clojure/